# How to get cell value on React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I develop in React.js, and I'm using [React-Table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table). I need to get cell value in a specific column.

I have made a reference to the table component to access its internal state.

but I don't know where to find the cell value from a column.

Is it possible to get cell value on a column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are creating the columns, for the Cell section you can specify a function which will read the value of the cell

`Cell: v => console.log(v.value)`

[Columns](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#columns)

Answer (score 1):

For React table **v8** or above, the cell API changes to `getValue()` function instead of `value`

```
cell: v => <i> { v.getValue() } </i>
```