# Get cell value from React table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

[image: ReactTable]

I have a react table that looks like this.
I want to be able to click each individual cell and get the value. I know you can get the entire row, but I only want each individual cell when it's clicked so I can save it in state like this

```
{
    "Team": GB,
    "MoneyLine": -120
}
{
    "Team": GB,
    "Spread": 1
}
{
    "Team": GB,
    "MoneyLine": -120,
    "Spread": -1,
    "Total": 48
}
```

I tried this link [How to get cell value on React-Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488184/how-to-get-cell-value-on-react-table)

but it doesn't provide much explanation.

I need to get the team name whenever any cell in the row is clicked and then the specific value that is clicked.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import data from '../Data/data.json'

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`

function Table({ columns, data }) {

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()} >{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, _) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()} >{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default function PicksTable(){
    const [team, setTeam] = useState('');
    const [moneyLine, setMoneyLine] = useState('');
    const [spread, setSpread] = useState('');
    const [total, setTotal] = useState('');

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
        {
            Header: 'Teams',
            columns: [
            {
                Header: 'Team',
                accessor: 'team',
            },
            ],
        },
        {
            Header: 'Betting Info',
            columns: [
            {
                Header: 'Money Line',
                accessor: 'moneyLine',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Spread',
                accessor: 'spread',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Total',
                accessor: 'total',
            },
            ],
        },
    ],
    []
  )

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add onClick to `<td>` (values are in row and cell):

```
  <td
    onClick={() => console.info(row.values.team, cell.value)}
    {...cell.getCellProps()}
  >
```

Here is a full working CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-shape-jr8tm?file=/src/App.js:1325-1489